# San-disk 64 GB flash drive not working

Tags: usb-drive

Whenever I try to use my San-disk flash drive, which is slightly adjustable it won't show up at all. Sometimes, a file will flash into existence called Glide. But I can't use my flash drive at all. What is happening? And how do I fix it?

Comment: What does "which is slightly adjustable" mean?

Comment: It has a red slider and can change what length the flash drive's entry, it only goes a few centimeters though.